# Two column layout and first column truncated

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I am trying to create a `JPanel` using `BorderLayout` which contains two `JLabel`.
The first `JLabel` should use all available horizontal space excluding the space of the second `JLabel`.

At the moment my result looks like this:

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

[image]

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TwoColumnsTruncate {
    public TwoColumnsTruncate() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel left = new JLabel("This is a really large label and its text should be truncated with ellipsis");
        JLabel right = new JLabel("Some short text");
        panel.add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 75));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 75));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TwoColumnsTruncate();
    }
}
```

Do you have any tips for me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat to my surprise, I find that you can accomplish this by assigning the `left` label to `BorderLayout.CENTER` instead of `BorderLayout.WEST`.  I'd have to study the docs some more (maybe a lot more) to figure out why that is.

Comment: `BorderLayout`'s behavior is not well documented when the container is too narrow to accommodate the the preferred widths of the children. It appears to be always laying out the `EAST` and `WEST` components at their preferred widths, and using any horizontal space they do not consume to set the width of the `CENTER` component, regardless of its preferred (or even minimum) size hints.  Evidently it is even willing to overlap the `EAST` and `WEST` components, at least when there is no `CENTER` component.

Comment: `...at least when there is no CENTER component.` even when there is a CENTER component. EAST/WEST get preferred width. NORTH/SOUTH get preferred height. CENTER gets the rest, which can mean 0, if no space is available. Try adding 3 component WEST/CENTER/EAST to see the behaviour.

Comment: *"..to figure out why that is."*  That's a good hint that this a) Is possibly not the way to go.  2) Should have been a comment, rather than an answer. -- As it is, the OP is making guesses as to the required size of the GUI, and that is the core of the problem.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29137428/418556) for the correct way to go about it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, the question was "Do you have any tips for me to accomplish this?".  I answered the question with a useful solution to his problem.  In any event, although setting fixed GUI sizes affects the behavior of the program, avoiding fixed sizes is not sufficient to achieve the requested behavior.  The *core* of the problem is how the layout manager chooses a width for the left-hand label, and few layout managers are documented well enough to avoid some need for experimentation.  `BorderLayout` certainly isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Below, I have commented out your regular two lines to add the labels, and have instead chosen to use my own preferred method of getting things to actually look right, GridBags.  Here is an altered code of yours, demonstrating my idea.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TwoColumnsTruncate {
    public TwoColumnsTruncate() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel left = new JLabel("This is a really large label and its text should be truncated with ellipsis");
        JLabel right = new JLabel("Some short text");

        GridBagLayout layout=new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();

        layout.columnWidths=new int[] {198, 198};
        layout.rowHeights=new int[] {70};
        panel.setLayout(layout);

        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets=new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        gbc.gridwidth=1;
        gbc.gridheight=1;
        panel.add(left, gbc);

        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        gbc.gridwidth=1;
        gbc.gridheight=1;
        panel.add(right, gbc);

        //panel.add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        //panel.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 75));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 75));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TwoColumnsTruncate();
    }
}
```

As you can see by running this as-is, it will produce the desired ellipsis. Any further movement, can simply be achieved by changing the given insets and column widths.  I would advise fiddling with those a bit, as pixels tend to get messed up because of the fickleness of Swing, and its lack of image-safety.
I hope this solves your problem, and best of luck to you. P.S, feel free to send me a message if you have any problems with the GridBag stuff.

Comment: I find that with these constraints, the layout allows the right label to extend outside the component (so that it is clipped).  If the frame is made wide enough then the whole right label is visible, but at width 400, on my system, only the initial "Some" is visible.

Comment: `GridBagLayout` has the advantage that it affords the user a great deal of control.  It has the disadvantage that it requires the user to *exercise* a great deal of control.

Answer (score 1):

```
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 75));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 75));
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Should be:

```
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setResizable(false); // guessing you want this, based on the snippet
    frame.pack(); // Set it to the minimum size it actually NEEDS to be.
    frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Although your proposed modifications have merit, they do not produce the result the OP requested. Instead of the text of the left-hand label being truncated with an ellipsis, the GUI displays it in full.  And if the frame is configured to be resizable smaller, then resizing produces label overlap such as the OP described, not truncation / ellipsis.

Comment: @JohnBollinger *"..they do not produce the result the OP requested."*  Sometimes the OP asks a question to the effect *'How can I shoot myself in the foot'*.  This is one of those times. We should not be giving them instructions.

Comment: You have more confidence than I do in your evaluation of the right course of action for the OP.  Since it's not clear *why* he (thinks he) wants the behavior he requested, I'm not prepared to say it's the wrong behavior.  In particular, he might very reasonably want it as his GUI's behavior when it is resized (the explicit sizes expressed in his question then being for demonstration purposes).  I usually think it best to *answer the question that is posed* before offering alternatives or other advice.